# Execute a function after two or more events are fired in Backbone

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events

I have two buttons:

```
<button id="1">button 1</button>
<br>
<button id="2">button 2</button>
```

I want to make an alert message to appear only after the two buttons are clicked, this is part of a larger app for which I am using Backbone.js, so far I have this:

```
var test = {}; 

_.extend(test, Backbone.Events); //in order to use the backbone events feature

test.on("hello bye", function(){
    alert("works!");
});

$("#1").click(function() {
    test.trigger("hello");
});

$("#2").click(function() {
    test.trigger("bye");
}?);
```

This presents the message whenever one of the two buttons are clicked, but I need it to work **only after the two buttons are clicked**. Is there a way to achieve this using the Backbone.Events feature or perhaps using jQuery?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ccgRN/

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A minimalist implementation would be to create a couple variables to keep track of what events have been fired.

```
var helloClicked = false;
var byeClicked = false;
var test = {};

_.extend(test, Backbone.Events);

test.on('hello bye'), function() {
  if (helloClicked && byeClicked) {
    alert('works!');
  }
});

$('#1').click(function() {
  helloClicked = true;
  test.trigger('hello');
});

$('#2').click(function() {
  byeClicked = true;
  test.trigger('bye');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an idea using promises: http://jsfiddle.net/LFJGL/1/

Edit: fixed for older browsers:

```
var test = {};
var promises = [];
_.extend(test, Backbone.Events); //in order to use the backbone events feature

function GetAPromise() {
    var p = $.Deferred();
    promises.push(p);
    return p;
}

var events = "hello bye".split(" ");
_.each(events,function(event) {
    var p = GetAPromise();
    test.on(event, function() {
        p.resolveWith(event);
    });
});

$("#1").click(function() {
    test.trigger("hello");
});

$("#2").click(function() {
    test.trigger("bye");
});


$.when.apply($, promises).done(function() {
    alert('triggered');
    //might be nice to remove the event triggers here.
});​
```